# Valid email address format

Tags: email, special-characters, email-validation

I was studying the characters that can be allowed to be a part of an email address. Generally, we know that the email address is of the format **localpart@domain**, where **localpart** contains all alpha-numeric characters with special characters (special characters have some restrictions though) as per [this wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).

My question is, apart from the alpha-numeric and specific special characters [, ], :, - and . are any other special characters allowed in the **domain** part of the email address? (this question is w.r.t US keyboard)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain name consists of one or more parts, technically called *labels*, that are delimited by dots `.`. Labels must follow the LDH (letter, digit, hyphen) Rule in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035): The characters allowed in a *label* are a subset of the ASCII character set, and includes the characters `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, and the hyphen `-`. Labels may not start or end with a hyphen.

The "special" characters `[`, `]`, `:`, mentioned in your question are not allowed in a domain name. They could conceivably be part of an email address to a user's mailbox at a machine with an IPv6 address (`user@[::1]`) but email addresses tend to include fully qualified domain names rather than IP addresses.

Comment: is a@b a valid email address?

Comment: @link2pk Conceivably there could be a mailbox 'a' on a host 'b' on a local network, yes.